# SwiftUI List view have a different shade of color after I upgraded to Xcode 12

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, xcode12

After I upgraded to Xcode 12, my List view have a different shade of white or black (depending on Light mode or Dark mode) compared to its background. But my other List view in the same app is alright. Why?
Below are the screenshots and accompanying code. Please advise, thank you.

[image]

[image]

```
List
        {
            VStack
            {
                Picker("Numbers", selection: self.$selectorIndex)
                {
                    ForEach(0..<self.numbers.count)
                    {
                        index in Text(self.numbers[index]).tag(index)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                if numbers[selectorIndex]=="Alphabetically"
                {
                    ForEach(appointments_title)
                    {
                        order in
                        HStack
                        {
                            Text("\(order.title)").font(.headline)
                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(order.date, formatter: ContentView.self.taskDateFormat)").font(.headline)
                        }.padding(.bottom).contentShape(Rectangle())
                            .onTapGesture   { order.isExpanded.toggle() }//.animation(.linear(duration: 0.3))
                        if order.isExpanded { Text("\(order.descript)").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading).padding(.bottom) }
                        else    { EmptyView() }
                    }
                }
```

}

Comment: What's the actual problem? Which color are you worried about?

Comment: The Holidays List view is either entirely pure white or pure black. 
The Appointment List view is greyish and it doesn't blend with the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default behavior and will have something to do with the formatting of the list. I would compare both sets of code and check:

1. They may have different parent view structures (ie. placed differently within NavigationViews),
2. You may be using Sections or Groups in your code,
3. You can also add one of the ListStyle modifiers on the List to override their default style:

   ```
       .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
       .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
       .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
       .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
       .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
       .listStyle(DefaultListStyle())
   ```

Comment: They have similar structure except at the end.
Appointment List view
`}
            .navigationBarTitle("My Appointment")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {self.showAddDate = true}, label: {Image(systemName: "plus.circle").resizable().frame(width: 32, height: 32, alignment: .center)}))
            .sheet(isPresented: $showAddDate) {AddDate().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.managedObjectContext)}`

Holidays List view
`}.navigationBarTitle(stateTitle)`

When I commented out .navigationBarItems and .sheet , then I don't have that funny shades of grey.

Comment: Great to hear you figured out where the issue is coming from. Please mark as correct answer if so

Comment: Is there a way to have .navigationBarTitle and .sheet without having that shade of grey?

Comment: Did u try adding one of the modifiers in my #3 above? I think one those will change the formatting to the way you want. You may want to just put the same modifier on both screens, in case.

Comment: Sorry, yeah just tried and it worked. I used .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
Thanks for your help!